# How to autofill the page height with the item?

Tags: spacing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[6cm][l]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\minicontent}{\foreach \x in {প্লেট,সসপেন(ঢাকনাসহ) \hfill সেট,বাটি/বোল,ভাত বাড়ার ছোট প্লেট,বন প্লেট,লবণ দানী,গ্লাস,হামান দিস্তা,চাকু,আলু ছেলার কাটার,মাজনী,ভিম,ক্লিপ,বালতি,জগ,মগ,দস্তরখানা,চামচ,বটি,ঘুটনি,লুস্নি,দড়ি(রং সহ),বাজারের ব্যাগ,চুলা,সিলিন্ডার}{\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\multido{}{3}{\begin{minipage}{0.33333333333333333333333\textwidth}
জিম্মাদারঃ \\
সাথীসংখ্যাঃ\\
\minicontent
সামানার হেফাজত ঈমানের হেফাজত\\
সামানা গুছিয়ে রাখাও দাওয়াত\\
ইস্তেমায়ী সামানার হেফাজতে ইস্তেমায়ীয়াত  রক্ষা হয়\\
জামাত থেকে এসে তালিকা জমা দিয়ে দিলে ভাল হয়\\
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The number of items in the for loop fluctuates. I want to fit the page with the content all time.

Comment: So, what is LaTeX supposed to do?  Adjust the interline space automatically so as to fill the page with an assigned number of items?  What should happen when there are too many items to fit in a single page?

Comment: @GuM go to next page.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here comes an overkill solution based on Ti*k*Z, more precisely `tikzpagenodes`. Please forgive me for not being able to display the Bengali (?) characters, but I think the stuff will work for you with those fonts. This answer comes with a macro `\SpreadVertically` that spreads some items vertically in the remaining space of a page, and that also works in minipages. The red frame is just to check that it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\SpreadVertically}[2][]{%
\noindent\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(XL.base)]{\node(XL){\strut};}
\global\let\myw=\linewidth
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path let \p1=($(XL.north)-(current page text area.south)$) in 
\pgfextra{\typeout{\y1}\xdef\myh{\y1}};
\foreach \X [count=\Z] in {#2}
{\xdef\numtot{\Z}}
\typeout{\numtot}
\foreach \X [count=\Z] in {#2}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{-(\Z-((\numtot-\Z)/\numtot))*\myh/\numtot-((\numtot-\Z)/\numtot)*height("\X")}
\typeout{\myy:\X}
\node[anchor=south west,text width=\myw] at ([yshift=\myy*1pt]XL.north){\ListItem{\X}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[6cm][l]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\minicontent}{\foreach \x in {AAA,BBB \hfill
CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF,GGG,HHH}{\ListItem{\x}\\\vfill}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\multido{}{3}{\begin{minipage}{0.33333333333333333333333\textwidth}
\SpreadVertically{AAA,BBB \hfill CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF,GGG,HHH}
\end{minipage}
}
% just for verification
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red] (current page text area.south west) rectangle 
(current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess you might benefit from also having a small border on the right of your page, but this is of course up to you.

Comment: the output is ambiguous for me. see my output. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5kKG4hXfms/  https://ibb.co/jD2wjU

Comment: @alhelal Your link does not work for me and the output is not "ambiguous". Did you compile 3 times?

Comment: yes, it works. I didn't know 3 times.